# From Xcode 3.2.2 to Xcode 3.2.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

Yesterday I felt in big issue that happens with all my projects. After I installed new Xcode 3.2.3 (for iPhone OS 4), all my projects started to spit out the "referenced from:" errors. I noticed that in new Xcode all the iPhone SDK versions earlier than 3.2 removed. But I have a projects that built perfectly for iPhone SDK 3.2 on the Xcode 3.2.2 but has errors building for iPhone SDK 3.2 on the Xcode 3.2.3.

Thanks in advance!!!

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/528f450e71.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/528f450e71.png)

---

I've narrowed the range of the issue and now I see that this issue happens because of Reachability class, although it was copied from official apple sample. I think that the apple developers just removed the links to some standard libraries. But what links??? Anyway, I'm sure that someone saw this issue, because it's caused by Reachability (99% use this class)!

Many Thanks in Advance!

[screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/528f450e71.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/528f450e71.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the errors of type "referenced from:" just means that some framework should be added. and it works with Reachability class (just need to add SystemConfiguration framework). But the twitter api refused to work. That's why all my old projects refused to compile on new Xcode - because the Twitter api (MGTwitterEngine) do not work for OS4 (Xcode 3.2.3). :(
It's really really bad :((